# Is there a way to write a scss mixin to auto increment multiple classes

Tags: loops, sass, counter

So I am trying to auto increment a class because I want them to have the same css property. I don't want to have to write out all the css.

```css
.tab-content-1,
.tab-content-2,
.tab-content-3,
.tab-content-4,
.tab-content-5,
.tab-content-6,
.tab-content-7,
.tab-content-8,
.tab-content-9,
.tab-content-10 {
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab-content-1">div 1</div>
    <div class="tab-content-2">div 2</div>
    <div class="tab-content-3">div 3</div>
    <div class="tab-content-4">div 4</div>
    <div class="tab-content-5">div 5</div>
    <div class="tab-content-6">div 6</div>
    <div class="tab-content-7">div 7</div>
    <div class="tab-content-8">div 8</div>
    <div class="tab-content-9">div 9</div>
    <div class="tab-content-10">div 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .foo-#{$i} {
    padding:$i * 10;
  }
}
```

**Update**

I misunderstood the question. In that case you could try `@extend`

```
%foo {
  padding: 10px;
}

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .bar-#{$i} {
    @extend %foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not what I am looking for that put all my classes separately. I want el1, el2, el3{css property}

Comment: I had no idea sass had control directives... ((goes back to all previous sass projects to neurotically fix things))

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really possible to use Sass loops to increment just the selector without also writing a new declaration. You could just use a variable for the selector like this:

```
$j: 0;
.ff#{$j}, .ff#{$j+1}, .ff#{$j+2} ... {
  color: red;
}
```

But that doesn't really save you much complexity.

Since you want to use the same declaration with a variety of selectors, try using the native [CSS substring attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
div[class^="tab-content-"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will select any div with a class that begins with "tab-content-".